# global htaccess redirect for specific subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect all domains like `join.domain.com` to `signup.domain.com` including all URI Params.

I'm not quite sure where to start with this as this should be one rule that blankets all join.* domains on my server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCondition %{http_host} ^join$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://signup.$1/$ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try his rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCondition %{HTTP_HOST} ^join\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://signup.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```